Could not find libgeos_c
I'm running
./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf

to compile and install PostGIS, but I'm getting the following error, I don't know why this is happening.
GEOS version = 3.12.2
PostGIS version =3.4.1
checking for xmlInitParser in -lxml2... yes
checking for geos-config... /home/lzj/arm/geos/bin/geos-config
checking GEOS version... 3.12.2
checking geos_c.h usability... yes
checking geos_c.h presence... yes
checking for geos_c.h... yes
checking for initGEOS in -lgeos_c... no
configure: error: could not find libgeos_c - you may need to specify the directory of a geos-config file using --with-geosconfig


This might help you https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/postgis-users/2009-November/025085.html. Although, it didn't work for me
